# How to Display Chart Web Part Markers as Percentages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, chart-web-part

I created a 3-column SharePoint List with one of the columns being a list of percentages. Then I created a line chart Web Part with that list as the data source. I need the percentages from the percentage column of the list to display as the markers for the Y axis correctly as percentages. Instead, they are displaying as decimal point numbers. For instance, if a value in that column of the list is 15.2%, the marker for that point is displaying as 0.152. I've changed the settings for the chart and the list multiple times but can't get the markers to display correctly. At one point I did get them to display as percentages, but they didn't match the numbers in the list column. Does anyone have any suggestions please?

Comment: Today I went back in to the chart's Data & Appearance>Customize Your Chart> Data Labels and Markers tab and set the format to Percent, same as I did the other day. But this time it made my markers display as the correct percentages. Wonderful! Problem fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Today I went back in to the chart's Data & Appearance>Customize Your Chart> Data Labels and Markers tab and set the format to Percent, same as I did the other day. But this time it made my markers display as the correct percentages. Wonderful! Problem fixed!